# Interface with conditional properties

Tags: typescript, class, interface

I have a special type defined as the following:

```
interface HasNoName {
  hasName: false;
}

interface HasName {
  hasName: true;
  name: string;
}

type MySpecialType = HasNoName | HasName;
```

Is there a way to write `MySpecialType` as an interface?  It needs to be an interface because I want a class to implement it.  I can't write:

```
interface MySpecialType extends HasNoName, HasName {}
```

as I get the error:

> "Named property 'hasName' of types 'HasName' and 'HasNoName' are not
>   identical."

Comment: If you're saying that `HasNoName` has `hasName` set to `false`, and `HasName` has the opposite, what would you expect `MySpecialType` to have when you combine them? Sounds like maybe you just need one interface like `Nameable {
  hasName: boolean;
  name?: string;
}`

Comment: Basically I'm wondering if it's possible to create an interface out of a union type.  The interface you recommended is work but wouldn't be perfect, as I would prefer to have type safety against someone doing the following: `const foo: Nameable = { hasName: true };`.

Comment: To me, setting `false` or `true` is an implementation. So I might have 2 classes like `class HasNoName implements Nameable {
    hasName = false;
}

class HasName implements Nameable {
    hasName = true;
    name: string;
}`. Maybe someone else has a better idea though!

Comment: what if `const truethy=()=> true; const foo: Nameable = { hasName: truthy() };`? Do you think TS should evaluate the expression and do type check accordingly?

Comment: shouldn't this be `interface HasNoName {
  hasName: boolean;
}

interface HasName {
  hasName: boolean;
  name: string;
}` ?

Comment: ABOS: In a perfect world yes.  RezaRahmati: No

Comment: @sir_thursday, you have to check that at run time if that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really make an interface out of a union type.  But you can create classes that act like they implement union types, if you really need this... but it involves some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) because the compiler can't easily verify what you are doing.

As an example: make a class that implements the closest thing you can actually implement... something like `{hasName: boolean, name?: string}`:

```
class _MySpecialClass {
  public hasName: boolean;
  public name?: string;
  public constructor();
  public constructor(name: string);
  public constructor(name?: string) {
    this.hasName = (typeof name !== 'undefined');
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

This has an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) constructor that marks the difference between `HasName` and `HasNoName`.

Then make a named value and named type called `MySpecialClass` which is declared to act the way you want.  The named type `MySpecialClass` is just the union `MySpecialType` in this example, whereas the named value `MySpecialClass` is the `_MySpecialClass` constructor asserted to act the way you want.

```
type MySpecialClass = MySpecialType;    
const MySpecialClass = _MySpecialClass as {      
  new(name: string): HasName;
  new(): HasNoName;
};
```

And test using it:

```
const mySpecialInstance: MySpecialClass = 
  Math.random()<0.5 ? new MySpecialClass() : new MySpecialClass("Fred");
```

Well, that looks okay.  It has some warts, but depending on your use case it could work for you.  Hope it helps.  Good luck!